# Segmentation fault in caffe

Tags: cuda, makefile, osx-mavericks, dylib, caffe

Mac OS 10.9, OpenCV 2.4.11, CUDA 7.0, 
All env flags set to libc++

```
$sudo make runtest    
.build_release/tools/caffe
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.7.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/deepsamal/Desktop/Research/caffe/.build_release/tools/caffe
  Reason: image not found
make: *** [runtest] Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

As this could be related to library environment variables.
Here are all my env variables-
$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/local/cuda/lib

$LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/local/cuda/lib:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.132/mkl/lib/

$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH = 
/usr/local/cuda/lib:/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.0/lib:/Users/deepsamal/anaconda/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.132/mkl/lib/:

As both-

```
make all
make test
```

are running without error, this means library is linked but not getting loaded dynamically.

Cant figure out what could be the reason?

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: tried to see the runtime link of the libcudart library.

```
$ otool -L /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudart.7.0.dylib
/usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudart.7.0.dylib:
    @rpath/libcudart.7.0.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 7.0.29)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 855.17.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

EDIT: I tried to find all soft links to libcaffe.so, it seems the paths to cuda libs and cudnn are not resolved and that seems to be the problem.

```
otool -L ~/Desktop/Research/caffe/build/lib/libcaffe.so 
/Users/deepsamal/Desktop/Research/caffe/build/lib/libcaffe.so:
@rpath/libcaffe.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libcudart.7.0.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 7.0.29)
@rpath/libcublas.7.0.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 7.0.29)
@rpath/libcurand.7.0.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 7.0.29)
/usr/local/lib/libglog.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.9.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.1.0)
/usr/local/lib/libleveldb.1.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsnappy.1.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/liblmdb.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
libhdf5_hl.9.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
libhdf5.9.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.11)
/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.11)
/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.11)
/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libcudnn.6.5.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 6.5.48)
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
libpython2.7.dylib (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
libmkl_rt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
```

Comment: I don't see any segmentation fault anywhere there. I see a failed shared library load. Where is the segfault?

Comment: @talonmies segmentation fault when I run $make runtest .. Have to do sudo to get more detail. $make runtest
.build_release/tools/caffe
make: *** [runtest] Segmentation fault: 11

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` variable fixed this for me at least. I just had to add the `/usr/local/cuda/lib` as the first path (as you have done)

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.0/lib:
```

or as documented [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/caffe-users/BkMspfbYLIE/Pi6SUVANAKUJ).

Answer (score 0):

There is a terrible mess with OSX tools at execution time because of the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
I think this kind of hack should work :

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=''; make runtest
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the solution doesn't work. The only reason I set DYD_LIBRARY_PATH was because I was getting the runtest error, and it probably is a dynamic loading problem.

Comment: Ok so let's start from the beginning: you do not need to be root to launch caffe. You could start from a fresh brew installation (no macports), install cuda 7.0 (reinstall) and then follow http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_osx.html 
At some point (if you build with python) you will need to pay attention to the used python : you do not want the apple's one or you will segfault.

Comment: Just to be sure : I see in your dylib that you plan to use anaconda python and an intel compiler, did you updated the Makefile.config accordingly. Moreover  boost and protobuf need to be built using the wanted correct python (which is the system one by default but this is not what you want). You should also pay attention to openCV to not link against system's python.

Comment: Yes Idid the modifications in makefile.config.. Before trying to reinstall everything, I checked all the links to libcaffe.so, which has dynamic links to all the required libraries and found out that the links to cuda and cudnn are not resolved... So should I reinstall cuda and cudnn only rather than all dependencies ? (dynamic link output in edited post above)